# What might cause a laptop's fans to run at full speed intermittently that is not heat or dust?

Tags: laptop, fan

I have an Asus laptop that, when I first power it on, the fans gradually ramp up to maximum speed and then stay there until it is shut down. If the laptop is shut down and then immediately powered back on, the fans operate normally. The next time I go to use it (say the next day) the same thing will happen again.

It is definitely not to do with high temperatures or dust, since it is only the first boot. After that it is silent. I have updated the BIOS to the latest version and that didn't fix it. If it was faulty hardware or sensors I would expect it to be maxed out all the time or randomly, not in a repeatable pattern.

When the fans are operating normally, they ramp up when the system is under load and quiet down when not, as expected.

Edit: The model is Asus FX503VM-EN184T

Comment: Have you installed the latest drivers and firmware from Asus

Comment: One power supply OEM (Original Equipment Manufacturer) for a different line of PCs recently changed the firmware on one model so it runs full tilt all the time. Perhaps an inquiry to your manufacturer https://icr-am.asus.com/webchat/icr.html?rootTreeId=AM.US.EN-US&treeId=AM.US.EN-US.Notebook&tenantId=EN-US&_ga=2.31493310.1299060517.1560464600-1959752819.1554754024 might discover something like that. A review of their support articles found nothing on this subject, so you would need to contact them directly.

Comment: You might have a bad connection that "fixes" itself when it warms up. You should maybe install software to monitor the temperature, since the sensors may lie on the first boot. If high temperature is found on first boot, do a cleanup of all contacts and check CPU seating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was fixed with an update to the Nvidia graphics driver, so it was in fact a software rather than hardware issue.